# Error: class org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence has interface org.hibernate.ejb.AvailableSettings as super class

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

I am using Hibernate 5.3.1.Final and am trying to connect to Oracle in my maven project. The projects build up just fine but when I run it I get below error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in file
 [C:\liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.27\temp\KIR\WEB-INF\classes\context\spring-context.xml]:
 Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
 Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]: 
 Constructor threw exception; nested exception is 
 java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence has interface org.hibernate.ejb.AvailableSettings as super class
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1007)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
        ... 41 more
```

Bean in spring-context.xml

```
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="ORACLE" />
        <property name="showSql" value="false" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
        <property name="databasePlatform"
            value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
    </bean>
```

Below are the hibernate and persistence jars present.

```
hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.3.Final.jar
hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-5.3.1.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-5.0.1.Final.jar
javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar
```

Can someone please tell me if there is any conflict between these jars and if all these jars are required in the first place?

Java 1.8

Update --

Removing hibernate4.1.10 specific jars (core, entity manager factory) gives an error

```
 class not found :  org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
```

I am using this class in my persistent unit

Persistent Unit

```
<persistence-unit name="kirPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <mapping-file>\META-INF\orm.xml</mapping-file> 
</persistence-unit>
```

Is this class missing in Hibernate 5.3.1.FINAL jars?

**Update 2**

After changing the provider to `<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>`

I get below error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [C:\liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.27\temp\0-KIR\WEB-INF\classes\context\spring-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(Ljava/util/LinkedHashSet;Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/spi/ClassLoaderService;)V
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:439)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:277)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
        at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:71)
        at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1502)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1470)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(Ljava/util/LinkedHashSet;Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/spi/ClassLoaderService;)V
```

EntityMangerFactory bean in spring-context.xml

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="kirPU" />
</bean>
```

inside pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>  
              <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
              <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>  
              <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
              <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>  
              <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
              <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
        </dependency>
```

Spring Version: `<spring.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>`

Have made the exclusion because otherwise I was getting duplicate versions of hibernate jars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence` is part of the lib `hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.0-Final.jar` (or older) which must reside somewhere in your class path. You'll have to remove it.

Possibly you, your IDE or your application server failed to clean the target deployment folder up after you upgraded your project to use Hibernat 5.

Regarding the `persistence.xml` you'll need to migrate it according to the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-jpa-compliant) of the upgraded hibernate version. It states `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider` is the actual `provider` class.

Comment: thanks. I got rid of the above error. But now I am getting org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence class not found error. This class is begin used inside my persistence.xml file . I have updated my post above with the details.

Comment: Made all the changes suggested. However, I get some new errors after this. Can you please see the updates above in the post.

Comment: You are still using incompatible dependencies or have versions of dependencies on classpath left from the time before you started to migrate hibernate 3 to 5. Migration can be a big deal with you running from one issue into the next. This is out of the scope of stack overflow which is a QA platform. Try to setup a clean and new test project to see how recent versions of the frameworks in use work together. Read migration guides and recent documentary.

Comment: Thanks Selaron for all the guidance.  It was very helpful. I will try to build a fresh project and see how things play out.

Comment: You were correct. The issue was because of hibernate-jpa jar.
I was having hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar while hibernate-jpa-2.1 is needed with hibernate 5.1.  Your feedback was always very helpful. thanks a ton